# Communicating back to parent from a Webkit notification

Tags: javascript, webkit, parent

I'm using webkitNotifications and createHTMLNotification, etc. to successfully create a notification in Chrome (Windows).

Now I would really like to have the notification window communicate back (or at least set the focus to) the tab/window that created the notification (which *is* part of the spec).  I realize it's still in the early phases for this feature, but I thought maybe someone knows a way.  I tried:

window.opener.focus();

from the notification window, but it didn't work.

This page...
http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/web-notifications

says...
"Bringing focus back to the window that called the notification, as stated in the proposal by using window.opener.focus(), **doesn’t currently work**."

I was hoping it was either out of date or that someone might know a workaround.

Thanks for any information you can share.

Jim

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but here's what I'm using to return focus to the window/tab that created a notification:

```
notification.onclick = function() {window.focus(); this.cancel();}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
notification.click= function() { alert('whatever'); };
```

Works for me, but of course it's ugly...

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to communicate between windows using [shared webworkers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/#shared-workers-introduction).

I built [Toobify.com](http://toobify.com) with a "remote" button, a webkitNotification window that controls the parent. Have a look at the source of the project - if your feeling brave.

I'd also like to set focus to go back to this window. Seems to be a feature of the textbased notification not the HTML kind.

Answer (score 1):

## Short, Sweet, and Complete

It took me several hours, but I've got a basic example:

- [SharedWorker + Desktop Notification Demo](http://coolaj86.github.com/html5-shared-web-worker-examples)
- [SharedWorker + Desktop Notification Repo](https://github.com/coolaj86/html5-shared-web-worker-examples)

You'll have to excuse the brevity of the README, it's 3:30am and I was sprinting.

Ask me questions and I'll answer them and clean up the docs.